# Anyone know what brand this emblem is from?

Tags: bmx, decals

I am curious to know if this is a custom head badge or if it is a stock emblem. searched the images on head badge sites but no luck. I even uploaded image to search by image engines and no correct results. so wondering if someone knows this emblem decal.

[image]

Comment: The [colors and the styling certainly evoke Raleigh](https://www.google.com/search?q=raleigh+bicycle+head+badge&source=lnms&tbm=isch).  Do you have a better image?  What looks like it may be lettering around the edges is unreadable in the current image.

Comment: I've *seen* that logo before...  Where?

Comment: Is it the Rapid cycle brand that is sold in the US at Target stores? I can’t find an image of their head badge, but that’s what the blurry letters look like to me.

Comment: @Andrew This [RapidCycle](http://www.rapidcyc.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/logo.png)?  (Link to their website.)

Comment: I see a 6 letter name/word over the top of the big R, with the second looking like an A.  Its like a crossword puzzle with one word.

Comment: Do you have or can you get a better photo?

Answer (score 1):

It's Rapid, I seem to recall, but I don't know if it's the supermarket brand of that name.

The blurry pic shows 'RA' as the first two letters, but both Raleigh in UK and Raleigh USA have consistently used the same tall heron logo as the head badge on their products.

The model name of this bike as given on the frame would help pin the company name down.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  This would be a much better answer if you could find an image of the logo of that brand.

Comment: all i got is this pic, sorry!